# PHP : Find contents between a HTML TAG

Tags: php

MY HTML looks like this which i get it in a PHP string $output, what i need to do is split the string to display only the contents in between `<!-- start Default Content //--> AND <!-- end Default Content //-->`

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
        <title>Multimedia Message</title> 
    </head> 
    <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0"> 


                <tr height="15" style="border-top: 1px solid #0F7BBC;"> 
                    <td> 
                        <!-- start Default Content //-->

sdf sdf


sd fsd
<br> </br>
s
df
sd
f 
s
<!-- end Default Content //-->
                    </td> 
                </tr> 


     </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use a regular expression:

```
$matches = array();

preg_match("#<!-- start Default Content //-->(.*)<!-- end Default Content //-->#isu", $html, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
preg_match ('/Start Default Content \/\/-->.*<!-- end Default Content/',$output,$matches);
    $string = substr($matches[0],27,-24);
```